# What does 'using' do in Swift methods?

Tags: swift

I noticed that in I was getting an error unless I did

`animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`

However some tutorial present this method as,

`animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)` without the `using`.

It only seems to build if I include `using` but I'm curious as to it's role and when the change occurred.

Comment: Read the Swift language guide.

Comment: There are many questions on stackoverflow that can be answered by reading documentation. Also, although the answer is a duplicate I had a hard time finding it since it the question did not pop up during any of my searches.

Comment: But we're not talking about some unclear documentation of some niche poorly documented framework in some obscure corner of the internet. We're talking about the official language guide that covers all of Swift, and was the document that introduced Swift to the world when it first came out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

> #### Specifying Argument Labels
>
> You write an argument label before the parameter name, separated by a
>   space:
>
> ```
> func someFunction(argumentLabel parameterName: Int) {
>     // In the function body, parameterName refers to the argument value
>     // for that parameter.
> }
> ```
>
> Here’s a variation of the `greet(person:)` function that takes a
>   person’s name and hometown and returns a greeting:
>
> ```
> func greet(person: String, from hometown: String) -> String {
>     return "Hello \(person)!  Glad you could visit from \(hometown)."
> }
> print(greet(person: "Bill", from: "Cupertino"))
> // Prints "Hello Bill!  Glad you could visit from Cupertino."
> ```
>
> The use of argument labels can allow a function to be called in an
>   expressive, sentence-like manner, while still providing a function
>   body that is readable and clear in intent.